# Using integers from separate file to group columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use integers in one file to name columns in another file accordingly. For example:

File 1

```
3 2 3 3 3 2
```

File 2

```
0.2 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.98 0.98 0.02 0.02 0.97 
0.4 0.4 0.3 2.0 0.30 0.03 0.30 0.93 0.39
```

The first integer in File1 is a 3, so in File2 I want to designate the first three columns (after column 0) as `0_1, 0_2, 0_3`. The second integer in File1 is a 2 so the next two columns in File2 would be designated `1_1, 1_2`.

The expected output is:

```
  time  0_1  0_2  0_3   1_1   1_2   2_1   2_2   2_3   
   0.2  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.98  0.98  0.02  0.02  0.97 
   0.4  0.4  0.3  2.0  0.30  0.03  0.30  0.93  0.39
```

When I assigned indices in the following way, I just end up with the columns being numbered identically - is there a way I can achieve the desired output?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

file1 = "nsubs"
new = ['time']

file2 = sys.argv[1]

df = pd.read_csv(file1, sep=" ", header=None)
num = df.iloc[0].values.tolist()
for idx, item in enumerate(num):
    if item == 3:
        new.append(idx)
        new.append(idx[2])
        new.append(idx)
    else:
        new.append(idx)
        new.append(idx)

df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, sep=" ", header=None)
df2.columns = [new]
```

Actual Output:

```
  time    0    0    0     1     1     2     2     2 
   0.2  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.98  0.98  0.02  0.02  0.97 
   0.4  0.4  0.3  2.0  0.30  0.03  0.30  0.93  0.39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data you have, you don't really need pandas for the column headers. You can read them into a list and perform a list comprehension over them to get your headers.

Read in the text file, use the split function to separate them out, and then convert them to integers

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f:
    column_counts = [int(i) for i in f.read().split()]
# [3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2]
```

Then you just need to create a simple loop. Use `enumerate()` as you were to count the set, and the value to subset the next few columns. The for loop is shown for demonstration, but I suggest going with the list comprehension.

```
colums = ['time']
for i, n in enumerate(column_counts):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        columns.append("{}_{}".format(i, j))

columns = ['time'] + ["{}_{}".format(i, j) for i, n in enumerate(column_counts) for j in range(1, n+1)]
#['time', '0_1', '0_2', '0_3', '1_1', '1_2', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '3_1', '3_2', '3_3', '4_1', '4_2', '4_3', '5_1', '5_2']
```

In your example, `file1` yields a much longer list of columns than `file2`, so I had to slice them out once I knew how many columns the dataframe required. If your data has them matching, then you can use `columns=columns` when you create the dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
df.columns = columns[:len(df.columns)]
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)

print(df)
#       0_1  0_2  0_3   1_1   1_2   2_1   2_2   2_3
# time                                             
# 0.2   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.98  0.98  0.02  0.02  0.97
# 0.4   0.4  0.3  2.0  0.30  0.03  0.30  0.93  0.39
```

Comment: I really appreciate the extended explanation - thank you!